# Use HTTPS proxy on Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, http, proxy

I have been trying to do this since some days but couldn't get a working fix :/, so I'll just ask a question on here. Is there any way to use HTTPs proxies with Apache HttpClient?

And what is the fastest way to use an HTTP proxy with it? HttpClientBuilder#setProxy seems pretty slow.

Thanks!

Comment: It is better to show some code and where are you facing a problem? some example : https://gist.github.com/jabbrwcky/1751986

Answer (score 0):

I recomend [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api. You can build the `HttpRequest` with proxy as following:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.create(someHttpMethod, someUri)
                 .proxy(host, port)
                 .build();
```